# Web Scraping Blocked - Using Googlesheets IMPORTXML()

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ip-blocking

Was hoping someone smarter than me would know how to get around two websites Woolworths.com.au and Coles.com.au that appear to block the use of the IMPORTXML() function.

I am trying to do some personal budgeting and I'm trying to input the price of various products into my spreadsheet. e.g. [Toothpaste](https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/238473/colgate-plax-alcohol-free-mouthwash-freshmint)

[Here's what my spreadsheet looks like so far, I am trying to avoid manually inputting the prices of the Woolworths and Coles items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffHq2.png)

Have been trying importHTML and importXML.
=IMPORTXML("https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/238473/colgate-plax-alcohol-free-mouthwash-freshmint","//shared-price[@class='ng-star-inserted']")

[I was initially able to get some price data but after about a day it seems to have stopped working (I think they block my sheet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw9Lm.png)

Pretty tricky to work around so if anyone has suggestions for advanced Googlesheets forums to

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the difference between [https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hvUg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hvUg.png) and [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw9Lm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw9Lm.png). I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of this? And also, can I ask you about the value you want to retrieve?

Comment: If web scrapping already disallowed, then you can only try if `import Json` is working, although it need scrip to do it. I think it is advise stop web scrapping that website since it is their intention to do so..... Try `Coles.com.au/robots.txt` you will see it is disallowed for user agent

Comment: @Tanaike my mistake I uploaded the same picture twice, have now edited the image to give a bit of context.

Comment: @KinSiang I hadn't realised this. I was making this project for personal use and was aiming to save the time of manually importing the info. In the meantime, I am looking at using the website "Price Hipster" to attain these prices which seems to have achieved the aim of my project. PriceHipsters seems to have access to all the prices and price updates for these websites so I may be able to go through them to access these values.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, unfortunately, I couldn't still understand about the value you want to retrieve. I apologize for this.